# display only portions of lines from live log file

Tags: linux, grep, tail

We have a log file that I often follow live with tail and use grep to filter for the lines I'm interested in. However, the lines contain a lot of data I'm not always interested in but they have been difficult for me to parse so I only see the portions of the line that I want. The format of each line entry is primarily a list tags and the data (sometimes containing spaces) surrounded by quotes. Here are some sample (sanitized) log lines:

```
2017:11:29-11:29:56 filter-1 httpproxy[3194]: id="0001" severity="info" sys="SecureWeb" sub="http" name="http access" action="pass" method="CONNECT" srcip="10.11.12.13" dstip="14.3.1.4" user="" group="" ad_domain="" statuscode="200" cached="0" profile="REF_HttPro1234 (Campus2)" filteraction="REF_HttStu (Allow Policy)" size="6518" request="0x915a3e00" url="https://website.net/" referer="" error="" authtime="0" dnstime="1" cattime="73" avscantime="0" fullreqtime="61576999" device="0" auth="6" ua="" exceptions="" category="9998" reputation="unverified" categoryname="Uncategorized" country="United States" application="krux" app-id="826"
2017:11:29-11:29:56 filter-1 httpproxy[3194]: id="0001" severity="info" sys="SecureWeb" sub="http" name="http access" action="pass" method="GET" srcip="10.13.14.15" dstip="154.6.75.10" user="" group="" ad_domain="" statuscode="200" cached="0" profile="REF_HttPro1235 (Campus1)" filteraction="REF_HttStu (Allow Policy)" size="3161" request="0x6b4d5610" url="http://host.com/mini_banner.png" referer="http://www.web.com/computers.htm" error="" authtime="0" dnstime="0" cattime="64" avscantime="848" fullreqtime="50046" device="0" auth="6" ua="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 9765.85.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.123 Safari/537.36" exceptions="" category="111" reputation="trusted" categoryname="Education/Reference" sandbox="-" content-type="image/png"
```

One thing to note is that all the tags are not present on every line. For example, application and app-id are present in the first line but not the second.

Using the lines above as example input, an example of what I would like to have as output would be to only show the srcip, categoryname and url tags in that order. The desired output would look something like this:

```
10.11.12.13 Uncategorized https://website.net/
10.13.14.15 Education/Reference http://host.com/mini_banner.png
```

I am looking for a solution that is easily adaptable so on the fly I can tweak which tags are displayed.

Comment: The script in my answer should handle spaces in the value part. Please update your post above with an example input line that doesnt work for you.

Comment: @meuh I ran the sample log lines provided in the original post through your script using the country and ua keys. The returned output was blank.

Comment: It works for me. Make sure you are using gnu awk, or gawk. I dont see where a space might break the match.

Comment: I'm using gawk 4.1.3, so that might explain the problem. Looks like your version doesnt support `FPAT` yet.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a version without FPAT, though I don't have a pre-4.0 awk to test it on.

Comment: @meuh Your revised answer adding the code without FPAT now works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is highly structured as *key="value"*, so you can
write a small shell script using gnu awk which takes as argument a list of key names and just prints those values. Eg, `myscript`:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v lhs="$*" '
BEGIN{  FPAT = "[a-z-]*=\"[^\"]*\""
        nwant = split(lhs,want)
}
{       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
            start = match($i,/([a-z-]*)="([^"]*)"/,a)
            key[a[1]] = a[2]
        }
        for(i=1;i<=nwant;i++){printf "%s ",key[want[i]]; key[want[i]] = ""}
        printf "\n"
}'
```

which you call as `myscript srcip categoryname url`. 
This sets the awk variable `lhs` to the arguments as a single string, which are split into array `want` at the beginning. The lines are divided by awk into fields matching the pattern *key="value"* by using the builtin `FPAT` variable.

On each line, for each field we split it with `match()` into 2 captured groups, for the key and for the part in double-quotes. These are put by awk in array `a`, and we save them in an associative array `key` indexed by the key string.

Then for each wanted key, we print the value, and clear it for the next line (in case that line does not have this key). Obviously, this assumes all the data has the required structure, and will need changes to handle (") inside the value, or keys with non-alphabetic characters.

---

Versions of gnu awk (gawk) earlier than 4.0 do not have the `FPAT` builtin to split the line into fields matching a pattern, so you have to do it yourself:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v lhs="$*" '
BEGIN{ nwant = split(lhs,want) }
{       input = $0
        while(match(input,"[a-z-]*=\"[^\"]*\"")>0){
            field = substr(input,RSTART,RLENGTH)
            input = substr(input,RSTART+RLENGTH)
            start = match(field,/([a-z-]*)="([^"]*)"/,a)
            key[a[1]] = a[2]
        }
        for(i=1;i<=nwant;i++){printf "%s ",key[want[i]]; key[want[i]] = ""}
        printf "\n"
}'
```

Obviously, you could combine the two match calls into one, but this shows the difference with the original.

Comment: You can change this line `start = match($i,/([a-z-]*)="([^"]*)"/,a)` to this `split($i, a, "=");`. The result will be almost the same, except that outer double quotes will be left. But may be it is good, because of values with spaces, like: `ua=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 9765.85.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.123 Safari/537.36`. These cases are more readable with double quotes.

Comment: MiniMax, your split change works great however it doesn't work correctly when URLs contain equal signs as in this case: url="http://7.freeaddon.com/v1/geo/?uid=2sadfsa568-fgce-0gb2"

Comment: @AndrewS Then you can do this: `split($i, a, "=\"")`. Splitting not by equal sign, but equal + double quotation mark. But then another problem - the single quotation mark leaves in the end of the value.

Comment: @AndrewS One solution is return the missing quotation mark, after the `split` function remove it: `split($i, a, "=\""); key[a[1]] = "\"" a[2]`.

Comment: @MiniMax Your solution is definitely an improvement. However, after running several tests, the original script by meuh has a flaw where it doesn't correctly handle values with spaces. In the original script by meuh values with spaces are returned as empty and your modified version returns just the first word with no closing quotation mark.

Comment: @AndrewS Do you use `gawk` (GNU awk)?

Comment: @MiniMax This server has GNU Awk 3.1.8

Comment: @meuh It appears that I can add printf substr($0,0,20) just before the FOR loop in order to print the timestamp of each line. I'd like to be able to have an IF statement that checks for the presence of a custom key datetime and only then print the timestamp. How could I do that? Every variable I tried to access seems to only have the log line data but not the command line parameter key values.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the keys to the array `want` contains the cli params, so you should be able to say `if("datetime" in want)print ...` Otherwise, don't hesitate to start a new Post with your problem.

Comment: @meuh Thanks! That was enough to get me started. The want array only has index numbers so your if statement above didn't work. However, I ended up adding the following line just before the while loop to create the missing named array element and everything else worked without further changes: key["datetime"] = substr($0,0,19)

Comment: @AndrewS well caught, and a much more elegant solution than I was working towards.

Answer (score 1):

Using (POSIX-compliant) `sed`...

```
sed 's/.* srcip="\([^"]*\)" .* url="\([^"]*\)" .* categoryname="\([^"]*\)" .*/\1 \3 \2/' logfile
```

Nothing fancy here, just find the keys and surround the values with parens `\(..\)` which allows them to be used as back-references. Then we substitute for the string with just the back-refs, space-delimited, ordered per your requirement: `\1 \3 \2`.

Output:

```
10.11.12.13 Uncategorized https://website.net/
10.13.14.15 Education/Reference http://host.com/mini_banner.png
```

---

If the logs contain strings that don't have all of these keys then you can use:

```
sed -n 's/.* srcip="\([^"]*\)" .* url="\([^"]*\)" .* categoryname="\([^"]*\)" .*/\1 \3 \2/p' logfile
```

This will only print lines that match the pattern.

And, of course, if you want to use these in a streaming fashion just remove the filename and do `[something sending logs to stdout] | sed ...`

Comment: Your sed solution works well. I had previously tried using sed but the part I was missing was the correct regular expression of [^"] to match the next quotation mark versus skipping to the last quotation mark. Also the -n to only show matches was very helpful. Thanks!